# Put getElementById() at the bottom

Tags: javascript, egl

I have the following code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Hello";
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="txt"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and of course the text "Hello" isn't displayed because it's before the div. However because i use egl i can put js code only on head.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: In what way does EGL prevent you from putting scripts where you want to put them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for your page to be ready before your code can execute on markup in the page.  For example, use `window.onload` handler as in the example below.  There are nicer ways to do this such as jQuery methods, but this will serve as an example of what you need.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.onload = function ()
         {
              document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Hello";
         }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="txt"></div>

</body>
</html>
```